# While loop with && ends if either is true, instead of if both are true

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, linked-list

I have this while loop that always ends if one of the cases is true, instead of only ending if both are true. Does anyone have any clue why?

```
while (f != NULL && t!= NULL)
{
    if ( f == NULL && t!= NULL)
    {
        cout << t->start_byte << " - "<< left<< setw(20) << t-> end_byte <<  t->id << endl;
        t=t->next;
    }
    else if (t == NULL && f != NULL)
    {
        cout << f->start_byte << " - "<< left<< setw(21) << f-> end_byte << "FREE" << endl;
        f=f->next;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << f->start_byte << " - "<< left<< setw(21) << f-> end_byte << "FREE" << endl;
        cout << t->start_byte << " - "<< left<< setw(21) << t-> end_byte <<  t->id << endl;
        cout<< " IM IN THE BOTH " << endl;
        t=t->next;
        f=f->next;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows, keep in mind that in this particular example the loop should have one more FREE output at the bottom  because my f linked list has 3 nodes, and my t linked list has 2

```
  Memory Block Job

0 - 99                   FREE
100 - 129                  3
 IM IN THE BOTH
130 - 149                  FREE
150 - 179                  2
 IM IN THE BOTH
```

Comment: _"instead of only ending if both are true"_ You mean _if either condition is false_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while (f != NULL && t!= NULL)
```

will evaluate true only if both `f` and `t` are non-NULL.

Judging from the code inside the loop, you want it to run while either variable is non-NULL.  You need to use logical OR `||` instead:

```
while (f != NULL || t!= NULL)
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake on my part, thank you very much! I'm not sure why i was not thinking it through like that. I had it stuck in my mind that the opposite would happen and did not even think to try the other option.

Answer (score 3):

When you have `boolean1 && boolean2`, here are possible scenarios:

```
boolean1 |    boolean2    | result 
---------+----------------+-------
  true   |      true      | true
  true   |      false     | false
  false  | doesn't matter | false
```

When `boolean1` is `false`, due to [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), `boolean2` won't be even reached, since the result is `false` anyway. So in this case the loop condition will be satisfied *only* if the two sides are `true`.

You might want to use `||` instead of `&&`:

```
while(f != NULL || t!= NULL)
```

And now the condition will be satisfied if only one of the two is `true`.

Comment: The `true`/`false` case is not covered by your table.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is running as long as both conditions are true, and ends as soon as one of them is false.

If you want to it to run as long as one of them is true, and end as soon as both of them are false, then:

**Change the `&&` to `||`.**